# Simplify sufficient to check for infinity?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a function, comprising of many functions in its definition, which is being simplified to ComplexInfinity. My goal right now is to check each of the comprising function for infinity.

If I run `Simplify` on a particular comprising function then I get a form for that function quickly (< 10 seconds) but if I run `FullSimplify` then it takes about half an hour to give me an output. Other comprising functions are quite likely to take several hours for `FullSimplify` to analyse, so my question is : Is it sufficient to verify for no infinity errors in `Simplify` ? Am I guaranteed that my expression is fine if `Simplify` okays it? Alternatively, what if `Simplify` throws an error (like time out) while evaluating a function but using `Plot` to plot that function throws no error? Can I be sure that my expression is fine?

Comment: Have you tried something like `With[{expr = x/0, vars = {x}}, 
 TrueQ@Resolve[ForAll[vars, 1/expr == 0]]]`? This should return `True` if determinate `expr` is trivially infinite for all `x` and `False` otherwise. Without specific examples it's a little hard to give very good advice, so please add an example if possible.

Comment: @kirma I think I can make that work. I will try to modify this to return `True` if there is atleast one value of `x` for which my `expr` is infinite. Thanks. :)

Comment: Replace `ForAll` with `Exists`, this should return `True` if it is "trivial" (the amount of work `Resolve` does) to find an infinite value of `expr` with some `x`). You may want to drop `TrueQ@` from the mix if you want to see more specifically what expressions that would otherwise return `False` would return; it is possible that they return conditions for infinity of `expr`.